# In p5.js I am trying to run two music tracks, one of the music tracks keeps on creating an error of undefined when doing .play() command

Tags: javascript, undefined, p5.js

This is a small snippet of a simple spaceship adventures game I'm coding for my science class. The goal is to make the soundtrack menu music play when the background music is not. The code that does not work is `menuMusic.play();` once I remove this line everything runs
perfectly.

I have tried to replace the `menuMusic.play();` with the one that does work, `backgroundMusic.play();`,but it still gives the error of undefined, so its not a problem with the music needing replacing. I have also tried separating both parts of the code but that did nothing to help.

```js
//Variables
var menu = 0; // 0 = main menu, 1 = level select, 2 = gameplay, 3 = you died, 4 = level complete, 5 = credits
var playedMenuMusic = false; //false has not played, true has played
var playedBackgroundMusic = false; //false has not played, true has played


function setup() {
  menuMusic = loadSound("centaur-forest-60695.mp3");
  backgroundMusic = loadSound("8bit-music-for-game-68698.mp3");
}

function draw() {
  if (
    (menu == 2 || menu == 5) &&
    backgroundMusic.isPlaying() == false &&
    playedBackgroundMusic == false
  ) {
    //Background Music
    backgroundMusic.play();
    playedBackgroundMusic = true;
    //Menu Music
    menuMusic.stop();
    playedMenuMusic = false;
  }
  if (
    (menu == 0 || menu == 1 || menu == 3 || menu == 4) &&
    menuMusic.isPlaying() == false &&
    playedMenuMusic == false
  ) {
    //Menu Music
    menuMusic.play();
    playedMenuMusic = true;
    //Background Music
    backgroundMusic.stop();
    playedBackgroundMusic = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In JS, use `lowerCamelCase` for variables and `UpperPascalCase` for classes. Doing otherwise makes it hard for others to read your code. What sort of functionality are you trying to implement here? It'd be good to see the specification written, with context for the app you're creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I fixed it, the problem was

```
menuMusic = loadSound("centaur-forest-60695.mp3"); and 
backgroundMusic = loadSound("8bit-music-for-game-68698.mp3");
```

was in `setup()` instead of `preload()`